# 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'bookstore.user' doesn't exist in engine'

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

This code was working before. Now it doesn't when I try to sign in. This is the error which I get.

**Fatal error**:

> Uncaught exception'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
>   table or view not found: 1932 Table 'mhaonlineshop.users' doesn't
>   exist in engine'........  DO->query('select * FROM t...') #1 {main}
>   thrown in H:\Aston University\New folder\htdocs\xampp\login.php on
>   line 23((this line has this code = $result = $db->query($query);))

I would very much appreciate what is going on how it can be resolved. thank you.

```
  <?php
     session_start();

 include ("db_connect.php"); 
include("shared.php");

     if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){

         $username = $_POST['ID'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];

     $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=mhaonlineshop;host=localhost", "root", "");
     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


     $query = "select * FROM users where ID= '$username' AND password = '$password'";

     $result = $db->query($query);

      if ($result -> rowCount()==1){
     $firstrow = $result->fetch(); 

         $_SESSION['ID'] = $firstrow[0];
         $_SESSION['money'] = $firstrow[6];
         $_SESSION['admin'] = $firstrow[5];


                  if ($_SESSION['admin'] == "0"){
                 header("Location: mhaonlineshopcatalogue.php");
             }else if ($_SESSION['staff'] == "1"){
             header("Location: cart.php");
            }
        } else {
            echo "<h1>Please enter correct password</h1>";

        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from serious security issues in your code, the above message states that the table users is not present in your database. Did you check the database?

Concerning the security issues: Imagine what would happen, when a user enters

```
' OR password LIKE '%
```

as user name or password...

...you should never use unsanitized post var strings like that in a query. (And also not store plain passwords to the database; consider using hashed passwords.)

Comment: The phrase to Google for is `parameter binding`